# About productFlavors with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have some problem with `productFlavors`. For example in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="UMENG_APPKEY" android:value="51a5692756240bfa33032a55" />
<meta-data android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL" android:value="Authority" />
```

I want to change the `Authority` value through `productFlavors`, anyone can help me?
I try to set like this but it doesn't work.

```
    productFlavors {
    playstore {
        packageName='com.android.newsp.playstore'
        versionCode 15
        UMENG_CHANNEL="Authority"
    }
    hiapk {
        packageName='com.android.newsp.hiapk'
        versionCode 100
        UMENG_CHANNEL="ChannelA"
    }
}
```

I try it, I found the mainfests don't merged as I hope. I copy two `AndroidManifest.xml` and change the `UMENG_CHANNEL` value. Then I put them in the folder:

```
    productFlavors {
    playstore {
        packageName='com.android.newsp.playstore'
        versionCode 15
    }
    hiapk {
        packageName='com.android.newsp.hiapk'
        versionCode 100
    }
}

sourceSets {
    hiapk {
        manifest.srcFile 'hiapk/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    playstore {
        manifest.srcFile 'playstore/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manifests are merged so you could put your manifest differences in the flavors manifests

src/playstore/AndroidManifest.xml contains

```
 <meta-data android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL" android:value="Authority" />
```

and src/hiapk/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL" android:value="ChannelA" />
```

Comment: I try it, I found the mainfests don't merged as I hope. I copy two AndroidManifest.xml  and change the UMENG_CHANNEL value, then,put they in the folder. look this,

Comment: productFlavors {
        playstore {
            packageName='com.android.newsp.playstore'
            versionCode 15
            

        }
        hiapk {
            packageName='com.android.newsp.hiapk'
            versionCode 100
            
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

        hiapk {
            manifest.srcFile 'hiapk/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        playstore {
            manifest.srcFile 'playstore/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    }

Comment: Sorry,I am not good at use stackoverflow. anyway ,thank you very much